# WCF - DnsEndpointIdentityNotSupported with netTcpBinding

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding

I am trying to host the WCF service in WindowsService with netTcpBinding as I want to host it without admin privileges on localhost. 
Everything thing works fine while hosting it. It hosts successfully. But when I use the Service object to consume it in my client application then I am getting the error "PlatformNotSupportedException - DnsEndpointIdentity is not supported

This is how my config looks like:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyLibrary.MyServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MyLibrary.MyServiceBehavior"
               name="MyLibrary.MyService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding"
            contract="MyLibrary.IMyService" bindingConfiguration="">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding"
            contract="IMetadataExchange" bindingConfiguration=""/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost/MyService" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Please add some more infos. Show your client config etc.

Comment: @Mahesh I believe if you set the identity to your service name or the certificate name - you will not see this error. However if you found an answer to your question that is otherwise - please post that.

Comment: Hi @Mahesh, have you found the issue? I Have the same error on Windows 10 with Universal Windows Apps.